# Jenkins windows batch file- get choice parameter value

Tags: windows, jenkins

Im creating a jenkins job which has choice parameters. Configured with:

```
Name = Source
Choices =
EVN1
ENV2
ENV3
```

in my windows batch script

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo The source value is ${Source}
```

when i select choice parameter as `ENV1`, `echo` is not printing `ENV1` instead it prints:
 `The source value is ${Source}`

Expected:
`The source value is ENV1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your batch script to:
`echo The source value is %Source%`

This will print the currently selected value e.g `EVN1`. You don't need the delayedexpansion either.